# How to turn the numbers in the sequence generated by the collatz function into a string by using concatenation

Tags: python, collatz

The numbers in the sequence generated by the Collatz function will be put in a
string. Building this string is likely the hardest part of this. Get the
computation working without worrying about creating the string. Now, I'm sure I'm getting logically correct output, I need the help to create the string containing
all the numbers, separated by a comma and space characters.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeYf4.png)

Answer (score 0):

result is not concatenated.

```
def Collatz(number):
    result = ''
    while number != 1:
        ...
        ...
        print(number)
        if result:
            result = str(number)
        else:
            result += ', ' + str(number)
    return result

    n = get_input()
    result = Collatz(n)
    print(result)
```